How to change mapCenterPosition in React Native Leaflet without reloading the map?
I'm working on a React Native app and using the Leaflet map for displaying geographic data. My current implementation involves updating the map's center position based on user interactions or incoming data. I am using setState to update the mapCenterPosition, which is causing the entire map to reload. This is not ideal as it leads to a poor user experience and increased data usage.
Here's a snippet of my code where I update the map's center:
Every time setState is called, the map completely reloads. I've tried to look for solutions to update the position more smoothly without reloading the map, but haven't found a way to do this effectively in React Native with Leaflet.
Has anyone faced this issue and found a workaround to update the center position of a Leaflet map in React Native without triggering a complete reload? Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
 <LeafletView
            mapLayers={[
              {
                baseLayerName: 'OpenStreetMap', // the name of the layer, this will be seen in the layer selection control
                baseLayerIsChecked: 'true', // if the layer is selected in the layer selection control
                layerType: 'TileLayer', // Optional: a MapLayerType enum specifying the type of layer see "Types of Layers" below. Defaults to TILE_LAYER
                baseLayer: true,
                url: this.state.mapStyle
                  ? 'https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
                  : 'https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga',
                attribution: 'googleMap',
              },
            ]}
            onMessageReceived={messege => {
              switch (messege.event) {
                case 'onMapClicked':
              }
            }}
            mapMarkers={[
              {
                position: {
                  lat: [userLat],
                  lng: [userLng],
                },
                icon:
                  'https://payamgps.com/assets/images/marker/' +
                  this.state.carList?.[0]?.markerName +
                  '.png',
                // icon: this.state.user_last_car,
                size: [32, 32],
              },
            ]}
            zoom={this.state.zoomLevel}
            mapShapes={[
              {
                shapeType: MapShapeType.POLYLINE,
                color: 'red',
                positions: this.state.lineArray.slice(
                  0,
                  this.state.lineArray.length - 1,
                ),
                id: '1',
              },
              {
                shapeType: MapShapeType.POLYGON,
                color: 'black',
                positions: this.state.routeArrayData,
                id: '2',
              },
              {
                shapeType: MapShapeType.POLYGON,
                color: 'blue',
                positions: this.state.polygonData,
                id: '3',
              },
              {
                shapeType: MapShapeType.POLYGON,
                color: 'blue', //flag
                positions: this.state.flagArray,
                id: '4',
              },
              {
                shapeType: MapShapeType.POLYGON,
                color: 'red',
                positions: this.state.redArray,
                id: '5',
              },
              {
                shapeType: MapShapeType.POLYGON,
                color: 'green',
                positions: this.state.greenArray,
                id: '6',
              },
              {
                shapeType: MapShapeType.POLYGON,
                color: 'black',
                positions: this.state.blackArray,
                id: '7',
              },
              {
                shapeType: MapShapeType.POLYGON,
                color: 'yellow',
                positions: this.state.yellowArray,
                id: '8',
              },
            ]}
            mapCenterPosition={{
              lat: userLat,
              lng: userLng,
            }}>
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/refresh.png')}
              style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
            />
          </LeafletView>

